# How to mark output packet and make ip-rule see it?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have a routing configured:

```
# ip rule

0:      from all lookup local
25555:  from all fwmark 0x3000 lookup main
32766:  from all lookup another
32767:  from all lookup default
```

I'm trying to mark output HTTP-requests (e.g. `curl http://ifconfig.io/ip`) with 0x3000 to make 25555 work:

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0x3000
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that default route is required for the routing code to trigger the fwmark rule at all, else there's a direct "Network is unreachable" with no packet generated.

I got around this strange rule by adding default route to the nowhere at the end of the rule list:

```
ip route add default via 127.0.0.1 dev lo table 4222222222
ip rule add table 4222222222 priority 4294967295
```